# Basic Flask views questions app not found

Tags: flask, view

Hi I don't know why "app" is not defined. I have a very simple app and try to run it:

run.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import views
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

views.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

If I try to run the server via "python run.py" I get the following error:

```
File "XXX\a\views.py", line 1, in <module>
    @app.route('/')
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all your routes in run.py.

This is because, you have declared `app` in run.py and in views.py you are trying to access it.

Comment: I would like to try and put the routes in a seperate file called e.g.: view or routes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

`run.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import view
```

`view.py`

```
from run import app

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

On terminal execute

```sh
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_APP=run.py
```

then finally `flask run` or `python -m flask run`.

Also, its a good idea to switch to `flask run` from `app.run`. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/326517/why-is-flask-cli-recommended-over-flask-run)

Comment: I tried your version, I don't get the error anymore, but I get a 404 when I try to access the route ('/'). Why is that?